# Need to do equivalent of .Any in Entity Framework without navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My database has two tables, `Reads` and `Alarms`.  There is a one to many relationship from the `Reads` (1) to the `Alarms` (many) table.  For various reasons, the foreign key constraint on the `Alarms` table was deleted.  I cannot restore this constraint.  The `Read` object in my Entity Framework model consequently does not have an `Alarms` navigation property.

I have a boolean property in my `ReadViewModel` class called `HasAlarms`.  I want this to be set to `true` if there is at least one row in the `Alarms` table that is related to the `Read`.  I know that if the `Alarms` navigation property were there, I could do this with something like this:

```
var reads = from read in context.Reads
            select new ReadViewModel { . . . };

foreach ( ReadViewModel read in reads ) {
    read.HasAlarms = read.Alarms.Any();
}
```

However, I don't have the Alarms navigation property any more.  What is the most efficient way to do this in my current situation?

Tony

Comment: sounds like you'll manually need to join the tables, and then you can use your `Any`.

Comment: if i understand you removed the relationship between reads & alarms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need something like this:

```
foreach ( ReadViewModel read in reads ) {
    read.HasAlarms = context.Alarms.Any(a => a.ReadId == read.Id);
}
```

Also you can perform join, to get state in one query:

```
var results = from r in reads
join a in context.Alarms on r.Id equals a.ReadId into ra // perform a left join
from a in ra.DefaultIfEmpty()                            // on Alarms
select new { Read = r, HasAlarm = a != null };

foreach (var res in results)
   res.Read.HasAlarm = res.HasAlarm;
```

Comment: this will do a query for each `ReadViewModel`.  If you join the two tables you can do it all in one query...